# Access Database - moving months in column header to rows with the corresponding amount

Tags: ms-access, transpose

I'm sure this is rather simple, but I can't figure it out.  Working in Access - Budget amounts are entered by month with the month in the column header.   The preceding columns include Account#, CostCenter, BudgetCategory and an optional ID field.  I'm trying to transpose the data to bring the months into a row along with the corresponding amount.

Image1: Input format 
[image]

Image2: Desired output
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create  a table that contains a single column with 12 records with values of 1-12.  These represent the months.  Maybe name the field "Mo".  I don't like naming it "Month" in Access as this is also a built-in function name.

Create a query with your budget table and the new 12-month table.  Don't create a join (no line).  If you run now, you'll get 12 times the number of records in your budget table.  This is what you want.

For your new amount field, you'll have a formula like below:

Amount: iif(Mo=1,Jan,iif(Mo=2,Feb,iif(Mo=3,Mar,Apr)))

I just put in 4 months above, but you can expand to 12 months.
If you have space if field names, put brackets around field names in your formula like:
Amount: iif([Mo num]=1,[Jan Budget], ...

Comment: Great.  Joshua, if the answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer to "close" the question.